# How to replace error message with an error page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have when something goes wrong i display error text but i would like to replace this with a presentable error page instead of just text and wanted a little more help on how to go about this.

This is currently my code for displaying error text:

```
return function (req, res, next) {
        errorRepo.get(req.get('error'), serviceTokenHandler.makeToken(), function (err, errorInfo) {
            if (err || !errorInfo) {
                res.status(500).render('error', {
                    message: 'This is my error message'
                });
            } else {
                .....

                next();
            }
        });
    };
```

What do i need to do to redirect to an error page instead of just showing a message? Should i replace the inside of the if block with a method call that would redirect to another page?

Comment: Just render a view just like any other view.

Comment: Small comment: redirecting to an error page is not very user friendly, because many users won't look at the URL ("example.com/errors/500.html"). When the page says "try again later", then many people will bookmark the current page, which will report an error even after it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using express for your application. If you want to render a beautiful error page, you would do that just as you would render any other page.

The only difference between an error page and a "normal" page is - simply put - the http status code which ranges above 400.

E.g. you'd do:

```
...
if (err || !errorInfo) {
    res.render('error-page', function(err, html) {
        res.status(500).send(html);
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Express 4.x.

You can create an error.html file which you want to render when error occurs.

```
<html><body> 
ERROR
</body> </html>
```

In node render the error.html when error occurs:

```
if(error) {
    res.sendFile('error.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../views');
}
```

This way you can keep the html and node code seperate.
Express 4.x documentation for referance http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile